# How to save FolderBrowserDialog structure tree when loading the app and clicking the browsing button?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i click the btnBrowser it will save the folderDlg.SelectedPath :

```
folderDlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Then when loading :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxFileDirectory.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
        }
```

It will add the content in folderDlg.SelectedPath to the textBox.

For example :

[image: Saved folder]

but now how can i save also the BROWSER button when i click the button that it will be opened at this folder D:_Images ?

This is when i pressed the BROWSE button :
It's starting with the Desktop folder :

[image: Desktop]

and i want it to start by default with the D:_Images folder :

[image: The folder it should load when clicking the browse button]

I tried to do it with this line : when clicking the browse button but it's not working. Stil the opening default folder is the Desktop and not D:_Images

```
folderDlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
```

The code :

```
private void btnBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonWatchFile.Checked)
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        textBoxFileDirectory.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (radioButtonWatchDirectory.Checked)
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

                DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBoxFileDirectory.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath;

                    folderDlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                    fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
                    fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                                     | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                                     | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                     | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                     | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                     | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                     | NotifyFilters.Security
                                     | NotifyFilters.Size;

                    fsw.Changed += Fsw_Changed;
                    fsw.Created += Fsw_Created;
                    fsw.Deleted += Fsw_Deleted;
                    fsw.Renamed += Fsw_Renamed;
                    fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    fsw.SynchronizingObject = this;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Look at those first three lines you posted. How is that supposed to do anything useful? Debug your code, step through those lines and actually look at the values you're using. The issue should be obvious.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be setting the `BrowserFolderDialogs` `SelectedPath` … BEFORE you show the dialog? The line of code … `folderDlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;` … is meaningless since the dialog has already been shown/displayed to the user with.. `DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();` ?